# i installed apache 2 but in sudo ufw app list there is no apache applications in the app list

Tags: apache2

I installed apache2 by the command
sudo apt install apache2
and when i type sudo ufw app list
there are no applications related to apache like apache full etc...
It is showing like this
Available applications:
  CUPS
  OpenSSH
  Postfix
  Postfix SMTPS
  Postfix Submission
Can any one explain me what is the exact reason of this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For some reason the Apache2 UFW Profile is missing from `etc/ufw/application.d` So you have to create one for yourself. No Panic it's easy just create a new text file using this command:
`gedit /etc/ufw/applications.d/apache2-utils.ufw.profile` and copy this inside and save.

```
[Apache]
title=Web Server
description=Apache v2 is the next generation of the omnipresent Apache web server.
ports=80/tcp

[Apache Secure]
title=Web Server (HTTPS)
description=Apache v2 is the next generation of the omnipresent Apache web server.
ports=443/tcp

[Apache Full]
title=Web Server (HTTP,HTTPS)
description=Apache v2 is the next generation of the omnipresent Apache web server.
ports=80,443/tcp
```

Comment: The link to the profile no longer works, here is what I assume to be a working version https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/main/amd64/apache2/2.4.7-1ubuntu4/file/etc/ufw/applications.d/apache2-utils.ufw.profile